# How to get values of radio group from listview?

Tags: android, listview, radiobuttonlist

I am developing Android Attendance application, in which teacher can take attendace.[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4ibw.jpg). I have taken example from [here](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-radiongroup-and.html). But i am not getting, how do i get the values of radio button when SUBMIT button is clicked.

Attendance.class

```
public class Attendance extends Activity {

    private ListView listView1;
    Button submit;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.attendance);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);

        Option weather_data[] = new Option[]
                {
                        new Option("Student1"),
                        new Option("Student2"),
                        new Option("Student3"),
                        new Option("Student4"),
                        new Option("Student5"),
                        new Option("Student6")

                };
        RadioGroupAdapter adapter = new RadioGroupAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listitem, weather_data);
        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

RadioGroupAdapter.class

```
public class RadioGroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Option> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Option data[] = null;

    public RadioGroupAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                             Option[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MatrixHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new MatrixHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.heading);
            holder.group = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[2];
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                rb[i]  = new RadioButton(context);
                //rb[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.single_radio_chice);
                rb[i].setId(i);
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.weight=1.0f;
                params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 10);
                holder.group.addView(rb[i],params); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
            }
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MatrixHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Option option = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(option.title);
        return row;
    }

    static class MatrixHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        RadioGroup group;
        int position;
    }
}
```

option.class

```
public class Option {
    public String title;
    int selectedId=-1;
    public Option(){
        super();
    }

    public Option( String title) {
        super();
        this.title = title;

    }

}
```

Logcat

```
05-17 13:17:13.254 5141-5141/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: org.pitechnologies.teacher, PID: 5141
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.pitechnologies.teacher.Option[] org.pitechnologies.teacher.RadioGroupAdapter.getItems()' on a null object reference
                                                     at org.pitechnologies.teacher.Attendance.onClick(Attendance.java:40)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015) 
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: you can add those `RadioButton`s inside `RadioGroup` in adapter xml.. why programatically?

Comment: is your issue solved?

Comment: No i am still working on it, instead of programatically , i am doing through xml...

Comment: from each row you want to know which RadioButton (P or A) is clicked? right?

Comment: yes , but when user is selected all the radio button and after that when he clicks on submit button,  then i want all the values

Comment: the problem i am getting is how can i get all the values when user click on submit button

Comment: you need to create one more field saying `selectedId` (radiobutton) and when user clicks on submit, loop through array(weather_data), to read id..

Comment: check the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ListView re-uses the views so you need to maintain position of each view with respect to that view (row).

**RadioGroupAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MatrixHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new MatrixHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.heading);

        holder.group = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

        holder.group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                int pos = (int) radioGroup.getTag();
                data[pos].selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            }
        });
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (MatrixHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Option option = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(option.title);
    holder.group.setTag(position);
    if (option.selectedId != -1) {//check at-least one is selected
        holder.group.check(option.selectedId);
    }
    return row;
}

//get all items attached to adapter
public Option[] getItems() {
    return data;
}
```

**Attendance.java**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.submit) {
        Option[] items = adapter.getItems();
        for (Option opt : items) {
            if (opt.selectedId != -1) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Title " + opt.title + " Selected " + (opt.selectedId == R.id.radio_a ? "A" : "P"));
            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "Title " + opt.title + " Not Selected Any Button");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option.java**

```
public class Option {
    String title;
    int selectedId=-1;
    //your constructor
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but what is adapter( Option[] items = adapter.getItems()) in attendace.java

Comment: that's `RadioGroupAdapter` instance, make `adapter` global variable.

Comment: I got it, but application is getting crash

Comment: Getting Null value on attendance.java ( Option[] items = adapter.getItems();)

Comment: `RadioGroupAdapter adapter = new RadioGroupAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listitem, weather_data);` instead write like this  `adapter = new RadioGroupAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listitem, weather_data);`

Comment: initialize the global variable (adapter) only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement like this in Custom Arrayadapter
`radio[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(...)` and inside listener store the `value(boolean)` in some variable and include getter function to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the listener on the radio button in this way

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
    }
});
```

Then save the status of the checked button in a data structure that you like.
After that when you push the button submission you can read your data structure and send your checked/unchecked data.

I hope this helps!